# Xamarin Forms and Push Notifications not working correctly on iOS

Tags: forms, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Xamarin Forms App and have implemented Push notifications to receive notifications from a Windows Forms App.  I have used the 'Plugin.FirebasePushNotifications' Nuget package to make this a little easier and have setup the necessary profiles / certificates etc.

All works perfectly on the Android version of the App.  In addition, my iOS App will receive and display notifications sent from the Firebase Console when using the test function and providing the FCM token.

However under iOS, if I skip the test function and send a Push Notification using Messaging > Campaigns and selecting the correct target App, the Android app receives the notification whereas the iOS App does not.  I have double checked the 'bundle identifier' for the iOS App and it matches that specified when I created the iOS App within the FCM Project.  I have also set the APNs authentication key correctly.  I am also trying to send a test message from a WinForms App and again works fine on Android but nothing is received on iOS.  Any thoughts / suggestions welcome as i can't think what-else to look at now...

Comment: im having the same problem too. but my ios did not receive any notification even from testing from firebase console. have you fixed yours ?